# How can install ICU analysis plugin in window?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

I just studied Elastic search in few days ago .

Now , I would like to install icu analysis into Elastic search. But I can't.
Lots of document say use "sudo" but in window doesn't have it.

So How can I install ICU analysis plugin in window ???

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

1. Run CMD
2. Go to elasticsearch/bin folder
3. Run command: elasticsearch-plugin.bat install analysis-icu

That's all :)